Why does my Image and MediaElement not fit in Border without overlapping?
I'm trying to ensure that an Image and a MediaElement fits neatly within the Border without overlapping.
Screenshot from VS with labelling:

Simplified XAML structure:
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Border BorderThickness="2"
            CornerRadius="16"
            ClipToBounds="True">
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="GridBorderBrush" 
                              Color="{DynamicResource ColorBrand0}"/>
        </Border.BorderBrush>
        <Grid>
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid x:Name="Container">
                    <Image x:Name="ImageSource" 
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Source="../UIScreens/Images/PlaceHolder.png">
                        <Image.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="ImageSource"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="ImageSource"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </Image.Clip>
                    </Image>

                    <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer"
                                  Stretch="Uniform"
                                  LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
                                  UnloadedBehavior="Manual"
                                  MediaOpened="OnMediaOpened" 
                                  Opacity="0">
                        <MediaElement.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="MediaPlayer"/>
                                        <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="MediaPlayer"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </MediaElement.Clip>
                    </MediaElement>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>

What can I do to ensure that the Image (and the MediaElement) stays within the Border and respects the rounded corners without overlap?

PS: Setting RadiusX and RadiusY of the RectangleGeometry does not meet my additional requirements.
The item should just be 100% inside the Border.

@Sinatr I want that the content (the image and the media element) inside the Border respects the CornerRadius and does not overlap.

Layout in WPF is made for rectangles. If you need something more shape-oriented, then you need to do all the math yourself or apply some tricks. Try adding margin to a Grid or ViewBox.

I'm not sure to understand what you want to do about the corners. Does the image should be clipped ? or do you want to apply a simple padding ?

@Orace I edited my question and I hope it's clear now what I want.
